# I want to change a column type but don't want to lose my data

Tags: column

I have a column using the "Currency" format. Since it only allows one type of currency I need to change the column type to single line of text. I will be using radio buttons to select the different currencies used. There are already a bunch of list items using the $ currency format, if I change to single line of text, will it affect the entries?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a quick test in SP2013, it correctly converted my currency column to a single line of text, but only as a number, no dollar sign.

Another option might be to create a column "Price in USD", "Price in Euro", etc. this would allow more flexibility for items that may have prices in multiple markets and aren't formulaically dependent. You could also look at using a computed column and a custom view to unify the different values.